# Accessing variables of non-inherited class

Tags: python, class, inheritance, subprocess

I have a module `testrun.py` which runs all the tests. One of the tests is `SWStatus` such that

```
class HWStatus(myTest):
    check = []
    def __init__(self):
        super(SWStatus, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def work(self):
        """
        some functionality to calculate the value of i
        i is either 10 or 20
        """
        if i == 10:
            status = True
        else:
            status = False
        check.append(status)
```

To run this test I do python `testrun.py SWStatus` and it gives me the results.

I have created `HWStatus` test such that it will run `SWStatus` test 10 times.

```
class HWStatus(myTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SWStatus, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def work(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            args = ['python', 'testrun.py', 'SWStatus']
            p = subprocess.Popen(args)
            while p.poll() != 0:
                time.sleep(amount_of_time)
```

When I do `testrun.py HWStatus`, it runs `SWStatus` 10 times.

I'm facing 2 problems here.
I wanted to have `check` list of 10 values. such that each time it'll append either `True` or `False` depending on the logic. But because I'm running `SWStatus` from `HWStatus`, `check` is getting initialized to empty list each time. So even though I'm doing `check.append(status)`, I'm getting just one value. How should I tackle this problem?

My 2nd question is, is there any way where I can access `check` list from the `work` method of my `HWStatus`even though `HWStatus` is not inherited from `SWStatus`?

Can I do something like:

```
class HWStatus(myTest):
    def __init__(self):
        super(SWStatus, self).__init__()

    def setup(self):
        return

    def work(self):
        for i in xrange(10):
            args = ['python', 'testrun.py', 'SWStatus']
            p = subprocess.Popen(args)
            while p.poll() != 0:
                time.sleep(amount_of_time)
        print "List of 10",check
```

Comment: You can access `SWStatus.check`, but that won't solve your problem, because you're running 10 separate subprocesses.  Unless you somehow save the data externally or add some interprocess communication code, you won't be able to access what you want.  It's not a matter of `check` being in a separate class; because of your use of subprocesses, it's actually in a separate program.  Is there a reason you're using subprocesses instead of just having `HWStatus` import `SWStatus` and call its test methods 10 times?

Answer (score 0):

Inheritance doesn't affect member visibility in python; all variables in python are visible as long as they're within the lexical scope.

The way you're running your tests though (in separate processes) creates different copies of `SWStatus.check`.  When you start a new process, you create a separate memory area that it runs in.  So, 11 copies of the `SWstatus.check` variable get created in your code, and none can see any other.

I suspect what you want to do is run the tests in parallel, in which case it's better to have the test return its status as an exit status...

```
import sys

if __name__ == 'main':
    t = SWStatus()

    sys.exit(not t.work())
```

However, if you *absolutely* need all of the tests to run in the same address space, you can use threads instead of processes.  However, you'll need to use something like a `Queue` to coordinate concurrent access to memory.